# DatagridView Multi-Row Select Not Highlighting

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am attempting to visually mark previously selected values when displaying a custom user selection control.  Multiple records are able to be marked as selected, however only one CurrentCell row is highlighted as selected.

- Multi-Select is set to true
- DatagridView has Read Only set to false.

---

```
HashSet<string> names = new HashSet<string>();
dgvTeamList.ClearSelection();

var ids = list.Split('|');
foreach (string id in ids)
{
    names.Add(id);
}
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTeamList.Rows)
{
    var id = row.Cells[nameof(AppDataDictionary.Employee.UserID)].Value.ToString();
    if (names.Contains(id))
    {
        row.Selected = true;
        dgvTeamList.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0];
    }
}
```

---

How can multiple rows be visually highlighted as selected in the same way these rows appear when they using Ctrl + Click to select them initially?

Thanks

Comment: Setting the `CurrentCell`  removes the previous row selections. Do it __before__ selecting the rows! And: You can only have __one__ `CurrentCell`!

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Moving current cell ahead of the select does not enable multiple rows to be highlighted visually because, as you indicated, there can be only one current cell.

Comment: _Moving current cell ahead of the select_ I meant before the loop.

Comment: Not even sure you need the currentcell. Have you looked at names and id to ensure that what you're finding results to a true `If` condition?

Comment: Charles - 
debug shows that the SelectedRows and SelectedCells collections contain the records selecteded, however visually they are not highlighted